# how to enable meld file filters

Tags: meld

I use meld normally in a git web project (system: Ubuntu-gnome 13.10).

I want it to skip scanning certain files and folders, such as the .meteor directory (which takes a while to scan).

Ubuntu-Gnome installs meld 1.8.1. It has under Edit -> Preferences -> File Filters an option to add a new file filter. More details: 
http://meldmerge.org/help/file-filters.html#file-name-filter

I added new rules for the file and folder I want to skip (and checked the 'activate' option), but it does not seem to work, even after restarting meld.

The new rules just don't seem to work - I see meld is scanning the .meteor folder and also, it shows the allegedly ignored file (index.html) as changed. I don't see an open meld bug for "file filters not working". I am inclined to think it does work, only I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas how to tackle this would be most welcome!

Comment: I've tried to figure this out a couple of times with no luck. And given the lack of instructions on the meld site, and no such recursive dir ignoring examples in default filters, i'm inclined to think that dirs can't be ignored.

Comment: what pattern you are using?
cause this option is working for me.

Comment: If you mean which patterns I tried adding to the ignored list: I narrowed it down to the actual directory name ".meteor". I suspected it was related to the fact it was hidden or because it contained a dot, so I renamed .meteor to tmp and added a rule to ignore it. It didn't matter though, it is still not ignored and scanned as all other subdirs

Comment: meld is a great tool -- except when it becomes unresponsive due to unnecessary scanning.  Not all folders are small and not all file systems are fast.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using Meld version 3.18.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
The meld documentation mentions [custom filters](https://meldmerge.org/help/file-filters.html). The settings menu is accessible when meld has the focus. It is located at the top-left menu of your screen.

I've made a screenshot. [image: How to add a filter in meld]

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer for my own question, somewhat:

Meld has two modes:

1. VC (Version Control): Meld compares against the VC image of the directory, and ignores the `File Filters` option
2. Non-VC mode: the filters kick in

This makes somewhat sense, a way.

I use meteor.js which has a `.meteor` folder for project meta data. In it there are pulled packages, their src and other meta. Many files/folder, in short. The `.meteor` folder is listed in the `.gitignore` file, so git excludes it. Meld on the other hand, revisits it and spends a while scanning its sub folders, which seems to take "forever".

I looked for ways to prevent it. One direction was to use the `File Filters` feature. Another, would be for meld (in VC-mode) skip ignored content.

Meld has a reported issue "Have meld use the .gitignore to limit scanned dir/files", see:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684400

As of today this issue is fixed (repo head contains it). Looks like it will be in meld ver 3.11.1  and onward. As expected, this fix solves my problem.

As a side note, it might take a while for this fix to get to Deb/Ubuntu, so if you need it, use meld head from: http://meldmerge.org/development.html

Answer (score 0):

Run into this issue today.

To add a new file filter in meld (3.16.2 in my case), open dconf and modify `/org/gnome/dconf/filename-filters` (json like string, easy to understand), and then restart meld.

`~/.config/meld/meldrc.ini` seems deprecated.